# Azure logic app - how to add switch case with multiple values for a case

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Here I have 2 cases, Type 1 and Type 2. I need Type 1 path to be followed for another value for data- 3.

How can I achieve that in logic app?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `Switch` on the following expression instead of using it on *data*: `@if(equals(data, 2), 2, 1)`.

It will go through the first path for *data* = 1 or 3, and the second path for *data* = 2.

Comment: Thank you! that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `Condition`:

[image]

Comment: I didnt want to use nested condition, as it always comes with the false part I cant remove. And, It doesnt look god.